# Query works in sql but not in php

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have the following query that works right in sql

```
SELECT *
FROM `dsrequest`
WHERE dsrequeststatusID NOT IN ('4', '5', '6')
AND CASE
WHEN ('Κ' REGEXP '^[0-9]+$')  THEN
dsrequestClientAfm LIKE 'Κ%'
ELSE
( dsrequestClientFirstName LIKE 'Κ%' OR  dsrequestClientLastName LIKE 'Κ%' OR  dsrequestClientEmail LIKE 'Κ%'  )
END
```

but when I place it in the php using variable instead of 'K' gives me wrong set of results, that is it seems that where part doesn't work at all. I get records that dsrequestStatusID are 4, which should not be the case.

Here is the query that I use in php:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT *
FROM `dsrequest`
WHERE dsrequeststatusID NOT IN ('4', '5','6')
AND CASE
WHEN ('$searchString' REGEXP '^[0-9]+$')  THEN
dsrequestClientAfm LIKE '$searchString%'
ELSE
( dsrequestClientFirstName LIKE '$searchString%' OR  dsrequestClientLastName LIKE '$searchString%' OR  dsrequestClientEmail LIKE '$searchString%'  )
END");
```

Anyone can spot the mistake?

UPDATE:

After the suggestion I manage to print the query, and it is the same

```
SELECT * FROM `dsrequest` 
WHERE dsrequeststatusID NOT IN ('4', '5','6') 
AND CASE 
WHEN ('Κ' REGEXP '^[0-9]+$') THEN 
dsrequestClientAfm LIKE 'Κ%' 
ELSE 
( dsrequestClientFirstName LIKE 'Κ%' OR dsrequestClientLastName LIKE 'Κ%' OR dsrequestClientEmail LIKE 'Κ%' ) 
END
```

Anyone can spot any difference that I can't? Is the regular expression the issue? Did they have any difference between sql and php?

Comment: Why don't you just echo the string that is passed to query() in your second example and check what the difference is?

Comment: I can't i use codeigniter, where it is not that simple to print the query, or at least I am not aware of how to do it.

Comment: I manage to print the query, and I have updated the question....query is the same, but results are still wrong. Please re-read the question to see the update

Comment: just some trivial suggestion, are you sure you are connecting to the same sql-server when executing the PHP code?

Comment: @Ryan Vincent, I tried that now, and i get all results (which is wrong) no matter what I type in the search

Comment: @Yazan,yes i checked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for putting you all of you in trouble. Problem was elsewhere with my codeigniter code, not with the query. As soon as I fixed that, query now works like a charm.